# CSS animation - images doubled

Tags: html, image, css, animation

Hi I've done animation is CSS at top of bootstrap. Everything is fine, but at first, loaded images don't hide before animation and most important after first loop of animation images starts doubling.

I have about 70 images to animate, every image is 1 second after another, they slide in line of screen.
http://scr.hu/30bj/mxy1h

In html it's defined as an div's with class of course.

CSS code:

```css
#skins{
 height:80px;
 /*overflow:hidden;*/
 position:relative;
 z-index:150;
}
#skins > div{
 position:absolute;
 -webkit-animation: sky 25s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: sky 25s linear infinite;
 animation: sky 25s linear infinite;
}
#skins .user1{background:url(../images/skins/user1.png) no-repeat center;width:110px;height:200px;-webkit-animation-delay: 1s;-moz-animation-delay: 1s;animation-delay: 1s;top:10px;}
#skins .user2{background:url(../images/skins/user2.png) no-repeat center;width:110px;height:200px;-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;-moz-animation-delay: 2s;animation-delay: 2s;top:10px;}
#skins .user3{background:url(../images/skins/user3.png) no-repeat center;width:110px;height:200px;-webkit-animation-delay: 3s;-moz-animation-delay: 3s;animation-delay: 3s;top:10px;}
#skins .user4{background:url(../images/skins/user4.png) no-repeat center;width:110px;height:200px;-webkit-animation-delay: 4s;-moz-animation-delay: 4s;animation-delay: 4s;top:10px;}
#skins .user5{background:url(../images/skins/user5.png) no-repeat center;width:110px;height:200px;-webkit-animation-delay: 5s;-moz-animation-delay: 5s;animation-delay: 5s;top:10px;}
and more

@-webkit-keyframes sky {
 0%{
   left:0%;
  margin-left:-350px;
 }
  100% {
   left:100%;
  margin-left:0px;
 }
}
@keyframes sky {
 0%{
  left:0%;
  margin-left:-350px;
 }
 100% {
  left:100%;
  margin-left:0px;
 }
}
```

Comment: please supply your html, or better yet, a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/auc3zs7k/ i see that in this tool images are more compressed due to animation time

Comment: will the number of skins vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try to move the individual elements, it is easier to position them all first, then move the container. Currently this animates them from left right, and assumes you know how many elements there will be (given you were giving them each bespoke classnames i assumed there was some kind of manual/programatic way you were generating these). It also runs last to first, so if you want to maintain the order your original code had, you will need to reverse the order of the HTML elements.

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/auc3zs7k/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="anim-cont">
    <section id="skins">
        <div class="8Wofel1">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="AbnormalPL">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Adamonia">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Agelika9">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="AlfheimPL">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ankos1">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Axmelka_">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="BlackKiller999">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="blaze4r">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Bramsiowelove">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="BrysiekxD">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="buuudzik89">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Chamosial">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Chicken">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Cocacolciaaa">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Drejken">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="EnderSweet">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="exsyther">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Filippexo">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Gluesh_PL">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Gumis">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="imago96">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Jelonn">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Juleczka_">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Kemotomek">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Koralina_">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="KraxPL">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="l4y0ut">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Lady_Anne">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Lusiaaa">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Majk21">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Maker">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="MakunaHatata">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Malpka2000">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Masta_Artista">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Merkador">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Mikejla">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Milotjan">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="minestee">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="MineTurboo">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Misurii">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="MrTheSkuller">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mr_Oxygen">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Mykozis">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Nafyrana">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Nathaly_">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Olusia_">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Pan_Zolwik">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Patex">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Patros2012">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Pawlkoko">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="PiknyKwiatuszek">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Pysia27">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="samoloth">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sync667">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="szok113">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="TheCastiiPl">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Tomek31">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="TosiaYou">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="vWhiskas">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="WaffOut">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Watom">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wiSien98">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="WoojtekPro">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Xana123PL">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="XPD">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="xRosenrot">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="zaqlinacz">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Zayawka">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Zupkaaa">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#anim-cont{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    /* add background image of mountains here */
}
#skins{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:200px;
    display:table;
    -webkit-animation: sky 70s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: sky 70s linear infinite;
    animation: sky 70s linear infinite;
}
#skins > div{
    display:table-cell;
}
#skins > div .inner{
    display:block;
    width:110px;
    height:200px;
}
#skins .8Wofel1{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/8Wofel1.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .AbnormalPL{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/AbnormalPL.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Adamonia{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Adamonia.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Agelika9{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Agelika9.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .AlfheimPL{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/AlfheimPL.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Ankos1{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Ankos1.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Axmelka_{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Axmelka_.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .BlackKiller999{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/BlackKiller999.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .blaze4r{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/blaze4r.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Bramsiowelove{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Bramsiowelove.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .BrysiekxD{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/BrysiekxD.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .buuudzik89{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/buuudzik89.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Chamosial{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Chamosial.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Chicken{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Chicken.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Cocacolciaaa{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Cocacolciaaa.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Drejken{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Drejken.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .EnderSweet{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/EnderSweet.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .exsyther{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/exsyther.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Filippexo{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Filippexo.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Gluesh_PL{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Gluesh_PL.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Gumis{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Gumis.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .imago96{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/imago96.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Jelonn{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Jelonn.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Juleczka_{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Juleczka_.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Kemotomek{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Kemotomek.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Koralina_{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Koralina_.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .KraxPL{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/KraxPL.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .l4y0ut{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/l4y0ut.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Lady_Anne{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Lady_Anne.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Lusiaaa{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Lusiaaa.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Majk21{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Majk21.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Maker{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Maker.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .MakunaHatata{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/MakunaHatata.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Malpka2000{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Malpka2000.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Masta_Artista{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Masta_Artista.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Merkador{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Merkador.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Mikejla{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Mikejla.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Milotjan{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Milotjan.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .minestee{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/minestee.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .MineTurboo{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/MineTurboo.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Misurii{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Misurii.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .MrTheSkuller{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/MrTheSkuller.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .mr_Oxygen{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/mr_Oxygen.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Mykozis{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Mykozis.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Nafyrana{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Nafyrana.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Nathaly_{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Nathaly_.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Olusia_{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Olusia_.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Pan_Zolwik{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Pan_Zolwik.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Patex{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Patex.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Patros2012{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Patros2012.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Pawlkoko{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Pawlkoko.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .PiknyKwiatuszek{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/PiknyKwiatuszek.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Pysia27{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Pysia27.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .samoloth{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/samoloth.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .sync667{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/sync667.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .szok113{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/szok113.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .TheCastiiPl{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/TheCastiiPl.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Tomek31{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Tomek31.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .TosiaYou{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/TosiaYou.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .vWhiskas{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/vWhiskas.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .WaffOut{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/WaffOut.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Watom{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Watom.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .wiSien98{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/wiSien98.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .WoojtekPro{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/WoojtekPro.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Xana123PL{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Xana123PL.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .XPD{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/XPD.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .xRosenrot{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/xRosenrot.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .zaqlinacz{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/zaqlinacz.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Zayawka{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Zayawka.png) no-repeat center;}
#skins .Zupkaaa{
    background:url(http://kwadratowakraina.pl/ccc/images/skins/Zupkaaa.png) no-repeat center;}

@-webkit-keyframes sky {
    0%{
        left:-7700px; /* 110px * 70 avatars */
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
    }
}
@keyframes sky {
    0%{
        left:-7700px; /* 110px * 70 avatars */
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: First time when I was doing animations in CSS :) Works perfect. Thanks for help!